# How to make framer motion work with styled component keyframes?

Tags: framer-motion

https://codesandbox.io/s/keyframe-plus-whilehover-zodx7?file=/src/App.js
If keyframe animation is applied to a component, any event like whileHover or onTap won't work on that motion.div.
The reason why using styled component for animating a div is sometimes framer motion for example couldn't change z-index during keyframe animation. I am trying to combine both styled-component with framer-motion together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply don't mix keyframes with framer-motion. The whole point of developing framer-motion was to make animations simpler and more React friendly than using CSS. Read the documentation and get some practice to get a better grasp of its capabilities.

I reformated your code, you can check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/keyframe-plus-whilehover-forked-y7iqr?file=/src/App.js